# C++ switch statement doesn't let me use more than one "or"? What?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, switch-statement

This is really weird. So I have this simple switch-case statement that's supposed to perform actions if the user types in a capital OR lowercase version of a letter:

```
switch (choice)
{
case 'A' || 'a':
    cout << "hello"; break;
case 'B' || 'b':
    cout << "hello"; break; 
case 'C' || 'c': 
    cout << "hello"; break;
case 'D' || 'd': 
    cout << "hello"; break; 
}
```

MS Visual Studio is giving me three errors for cases 'B'/'b', 'C'/'c', and 'D'/'d' that each say the following:

```
IntelliSense: case label value has already appeared in this switch
```

It does NOT give me this error with 'A'/'a' - and if I get rid of case A, it allows case B but not the following cases. I can't think of any reason why it should be fine with the first "or" case, but then get upset at the following cases.

Context: writing a container class and this code is outside the main function but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Any thoughts? And if it's not allowable in C++, is there a better way to include multiple choices for one case?

Comment: `||` has a very specific meaning. It doesn't do anywhere near as much as the English conjunction `or`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`||` is logical OR. Its operands are converted to `bool` - zeroes to `false`, all others to `true`. The result is either `true` or `false`, which is then converted to `1` and `0` respectively. So all four of your cases are equivalent to `case 1:`, and the compiler complains because you can't have two case constants of the same value in the same `switch` statement.

What you want is:

```
case 'A':
case 'a':
    cout << "hello"; break;
```

which takes advantage of the fall-through behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`case 'A' || 'a':` --> case 1:

Output of logical operators can be true(1) or false(0), so compiler will have multiple switch cases with 0's and 1's.

So it is not possible to decide which case to call.